# Can't set word paragraph line spacing to 0 by VBA, it shows error. (But success via GUI)

Tags: vba, ms-word

(I am not native English speaker)

I tried to use VBA to set the word paragraph line spacing to 0. My code is below:

```
Sub test()

    With ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).ParagraphFormat

        .LineSpacingRule = wdLineSpaceAtLeast
        .LineSpacing = 0

    End With
End Sub
```

But it shows run-time error,say:

> Run-time error '5149':The measurement must be between 0.7 pt and 1584 pt.

If I replace `ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1)` with `Selection`

It still shows error,say:

> Run-time error '5362':Line spacing must be at least {e}.

But I set the line spacing to 0 by user interface.

Is this a bug of VBA? Have any solutions? Thanks

In addition,

I use Traditional Chinese version office,and change the language to English.

[Linespacing GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VWHyR.gif)

Can someone tell me,how to show gif directly in page?

Comment: Did you record a macro when using the user interface to see what VBA does?

Comment: I can confirm that I get the error as well when setting linespacing to 0 by code - but I do get the error too via GUI. Same message: value has to be at 0.7 pt. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @freeflow  I just do it. The relevant part of recorded code is the same as my code. And when I run the recorded code, it shows error again.

Comment: I just feel the appearance of the document under 0 line spacing is better. @Ike

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding this setting. Just for your understanding: set Line spacing via GUI to "At least" and 1 pt --> I doubt that this is what you want. Propably you want to change the settings for "spacing before and after" or you want "Line spacing" = single

Comment: I am sure I want to set Line spacing to "At least" and "0" pt.As for "spacing before and after", I sometimes use the function. @Ike

Comment: You *have not* set line spacing to 0pt. If you had, you would not see any text. You have set the line spacing to *At Least* 0pt, which means a minimum of 0pt. If you set it to At Least 1pt the line spacing would not change.

Comment: I did. My operation steps via GUI is below (both Spacingbefore, SpacingAfter has been set to 0): ① set  Line spacing to single. ② set Line spacing to "At Least 1pt. ③ set Line spacing to "At Least 0pt." From ① to ②, Line spacing doesn't change in document.  From ② to ③, Line spacing really becomes smaller in document.

Comment: Could it be that you have some Add-Ins installed? E.g. I don't have the checkbox "snap to grid" - nor Asian typography ...

Comment: I am not sure if it's because of add-ins or Asian typography. I update the picture to GIF to show the real operation. @Ike

Comment: Sorry - no idea ... the only thing I can think of, that behaviour with Asian typography is different.

Comment: Setting the line spacing to At Least 0pt *does not* set line spacing to zero. When you use the “At Least” setting you set a minimum value. Word will then automatically adjust the line spacing to match either the minimum value you set or the font size of the text, *whichever is larger*

Comment: The question is that I can get the expected result via GUI, but can't get the same result via VBA.  Maybe I will try using "sendkey statement" to solve this question. @TimothyRylatt

Comment: You can get the same result by setting line spacing to Multiple and the value to less than 1. The exact value you need will depend on the font you are using.

Comment: I finally find that “grid” cause my problem.
In my Asian office version, the default setting of line spacing is “single.” But visually , the line space is too big for both Chinese and English words in documen. So I adjust the setting to “At least 0 pt.” And it make the line space looks normal. Now, I uncheck “Snap to grid when document grid is defined,” and adjust line spacing back to “single.” The line space looks the same as before (“At least 0 pt”). @Ike,@Timothy Rylatt